# listview row color dependent on value from DB

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, colors

Ok, I have app that store data about Items in SQLite database.
Items are listed by name and presented on main activity. Every item has some details and there is detail about owner. I want set 2 colors of rows on list. 1 color when i'm owner (i get true from DB), and 2nd color for other case.

```
public class BHItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BHItem> {
private Activity context;
private List<BHItem> bhItems;

private MainActivity cbOwn  ;
public BHItemsAdapter(Activity context, List<BHItem> bhItems) {
    super(context, R.layout.bhitems_list_item, bhItems);
    this.context = context;
    this.bhItems = bhItems;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvBHItemDescription;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    View rowView = convertView;
    if(rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bhitems_list_item, null, true);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvBHItemDescription = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvBHItemDescription);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    BHItem task = bhItems.get(position);

    /*line 49*/ if (cbOwn.onCheckboxClicked1())
    {
        rowView.setBackgroundColor(0x30ff2020);

    }
    else {
       rowView.setBackgroundColor(0x30aaffff);
    }
    viewHolder.tvBHItemDescription.setText(task.getItem());
    return rowView;
}
}
```

Even when I'm sending true or false i'm getting nullpointerexeption

```
//this is from main activity
public boolean onCheckboxClicked1() {


        return true;

}
private void fillListViewData() {
    bhDbAdapter = new DbAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    bhDbAdapter.open();
    getUncompletedTasks();
    getCompletedTasks();
    bhItemsAdapter = new BHItemsAdapter(this, bhItemList);


    lvTodos.setAdapter(bhItemsAdapter);

}
private void initUiElements() {
    etItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etItem);
    etDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDescription);
    etOwner = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOwner);
    etBorrower = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBorrower);
    tvItem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
    tvDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
    tvOwner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOwner);
    tvBorrower = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBorrower);
    tvCategory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCategory);
    tvReturndate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvReturndate);
    lvTodos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTodos);
    lvArchive = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvArchive);
    llItemAdder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llItemAdder);
    llIAButtons = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llIAButtons);
    llIAEditButtons = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llIAEditButtons);
    llControlButtons = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llControlButtons);
    llNewTaskButtons = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llNewTaskButtons);
    llItemDetails = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llItemDetails);
    dpReturndate = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpReturndate);
    ivEditImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivEditImage);
    ivDetailImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivDetailImage);
    cbReturned = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbReturned);
    spCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spCategory);
    cbOwn = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbOwn);}
    // this is how i get my value (owner or not)
```

logcat

```
09-11 18:30:15.201    5825-5825/szub.borrowinghelper D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-11 18:30:15.201    5825-5825/szub.borrowinghelper W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a99ba8)
09-11 18:30:15.211    5825-5825/szub.borrowinghelper E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: szub.borrowinghelper, PID: 5825
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at soulflier.borrowinghelper.BHItemsAdapter.getView(BHItemsAdapter.java:49)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have no idea how send the value to that adapter.
I'm newbe in programing
thx for any help

Comment: What line of code causes the NPE?

Comment: Also please format your code with proper indenting and finish providing the rest of your code, especially the `initUiElements()` method if it is pertinent to your question.

Comment: Can you please show the logs from logcat?

Comment: done, sry i fall asleep

Comment: And which line is line 49?

Comment: 49 line is   `if (cbOwn.onCheckboxClicked1())`

Comment: Hi! where exactly are you initialising/setting cb0wn?

Comment: Oh is see, you have cb0wn defined as MainActivity but you are trying to assign it (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbOwn);